# setterm: terminal xterm-256color does not support --blank

Tags: hdmi, display, setup

Since installing the latest build of Raspbian onto my Rasberry Pi 3, I've been getting the following error:

`setterm: terminal xterm-256color does not support --blank
setterm: cannot (un)set powersave mode: Inappropriate ioctl for device`

I've found a [couple of](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3713/stopping-raspberry-pi-display-sleep#new-answer) [posts](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34268/xterm-256color-behavior-on-mac-os-x) on this topic, but [none](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/752/how-do-i-prevent-the-screen-from-going-blank) have offered a solution to the issue. I've tried the solution listed [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3713/stopping-raspberry-pi-display-sleep#new-answer) e.g. adding `consoleBlank=0` to `/boot/cmdline.txt`, but to no avail. Also suggested [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=122140).

Within [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=122112) the above solution is mentioned but also that this issue could be a general bug with latest version of Raspbian (or Debian).

Is there any thing left to try? Is this indeed a bug?

Answer (score 3):

Not Raspberry Pi specific but I ended up here from Googling `setterm: terminal xterm-256color does not support --blank`

If you are ssh'd into your machine and trying to run the `setterm` command, you will need to physically be in front of the machine in a tty for the command to work.  Hope this helps someone

Comment: this should be marked as the answer for this thread!

Answer (score 2):

An xterm cannot possibly have support for power saving; you can't power-save part of the screen and have the rest be on!

Comment: Makes sense, but where can I change/find these settings? This warning appears immediately following a fresh installation of Raspbian.

Comment: *where* does it appear? The boot console gets TERM=linux on Raspbian by default, as do all the vtys. Are you setting TERM in your .bashrc (or equivalent)?

Comment: The above `setterm`simply appears as the first lines in the command line (desktop and cli mode). I haven't set anything as everything is default. After attempting the solutions listed in my initial post, I re-installed Raspbian just to make sure it wasn't something I had fiddled with. I came across this [post](https://codeyarns.com/2015/03/18/how-to-set-term-to-xterm-256color/) which mentions that mucking with `.bashrc` isn't a proper solution (granted the article isn't Pi specific).

Comment: what is running it? something *must* be setting your TERM variable to the value you are getting. I just tried a virgin jessie installation (the may 10 release) and i don't see anything like that.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. After another reinstall, I think I've tracked the source of the error. It's not an issue with Jessie, but rather the error appears after installing [openframe](http://openframe.io). The install for [openframe](http://openframe.io) appends the following `BLANK_TIME=0` and `POWERDOWN_TIME=0` to `/etc/kbd/config`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to turn off the display of the laptop by putting this command physically on to the machine and not via SSH:

setterm --blank force